# Is it possible to prevent an application (Chrome) from running in background?

Tags: google-chrome

I occasionally have to use Chrome while my primary browser is another app. When I open Chrome it keeps adding "Google LLC" and "Google Updater" that Mac OS X allows to run in background. I keep disabling these but when I reopen Chrome it simply reverts my changes back and I have to deactivate these again (via `System` > `Login Items` > `Allow in the Background`).

Is it possible to somehow permanently prevent Chrome from running in background?

I found that some version of Chrome - apparently an old one - had a dedicated system setting e.g. as clarified [here](https://www.microcenter.com/tech_center/article/11339/how-to-disable-background-apps-running-when-chrome-is-closed) - but it is nowhere to be found in my version of Chrome which is one of the latest.
I'm running Chrome 116.0.5845.179 arm build on Mac OS X Ventura 13.4.

Comment: @LincD. It does, thank you.